# JPA Access Constants from XML File

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea, mapping

i'm trying to map some classes using the Hibernate JPA implementation. My problem is, that I can't use hardcoded Strings or constants in the xml-file you can see below.
It is also no possible to use a constant like in the name-attribute of the entity-tag. `dst.ass1.jpa.util.Constants.T_CLASSROOM`

[image: Code example image]

this is the error message I get:

[image]

I don't know why I can use a constant in den name attribute of the entity tag, but not inside the column-tag.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3

Hope you understand my problem.

regards.

Answer (score 1):

For an attribute be used in an entity it must be "non-static".

If you map it in your XML, the JPA/Intellij will understand that you are trying to map an static attribute into the entity, and that is not possible.